# Generating fingerprint of virtual machines

Tags: c#, hardware, virtualization

I'm trying to create a fingerprint of servers using c#. It is important that the logic works for virtual servers so that the fingerprint does not change when the VM is migrated to another host.

I found this sample on codeplex: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28678/Generating-Unique-Key-Finger-Print-for-a-Computer
This is using the following components to create the fingerprint: cpu, bios, motherboard, disk, video card and mac address. I would also use the computer name.

Now my question is: Which components are not changing after migrate the vm to another host? I think the cpu and the mac address are not changing.

Comment: `Which components are not changing after migrate the vm to another host?` the simplest way to know is to create a program that logs the informations on a first VM, move the VM, reload the program and see the diff